# SQL check record in between two dates and time

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table i.e. **BookingDetails**. BookingDetails containt following fields.

> CustomerID
>
> DateFrom
>
> DateTo
>
> TimeFrom
>
> TimeTo

**BookingDetails** contains n records.

```
CustomerID    DateFrom     DateTo       TimeFrom    TimeTo
11137         2012-08-14   2012-08-16   00:33:46    03:33:46
11138         2012-08-15   2012-08-17   08:00:00    00:31:03
11139         2012-08-16   2012-08-17   22:46:25    00:46:25
```

I want to select records between given information **DateFrom**, **DateTo**, **TimeFrom**, **TimeTo**.

I have do following query

```
declare @fDate date
set @fDate = '2012-08-14' 

declare @tDate date
set @tDate = '2012-08-16'

declare @fTime time
set @fTime ='12:33:46 AM'

declare @tTime time
set @tTime='12:31:03 AM'

SELECT BookingDetails.CustomerID
FROM BookingDetails 
WHERE  (DateFrom between @fDate and @tDate) And (BookingDetails.DateFrom >= @fDate     and BookingDetails.DateTo<=@tDate)
and(TimeFrom between CONVERT(varchar(15),cast(@fTime as time) , 108) and CONVERT(varchar(15),cast(@tTime as time) , 108))
and (TimeFrom >=CONVERT(varchar(15),cast(@fTime as time) , 108) and TimeTo <=CONVERT(varchar(15),cast(@tTime as time) , 108))
```

Time save in database is in 24 hours format. Time used in query is 12Hours format thats why i convert it to 24 hours format in query.

Is this query is correct or I have to change it?

This Query doesn't return any value.  I want to select records between **@fDate** , **@tDate**, **@fTime**, **@tTime**

I expect Result for first two customerID i.e. 11137,11138

Comment: Are the data types `DATE` and `TIME`?

Comment: What results are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not pass the start and end as DATETIME instead of as separate values? In fact, why are you storing DATE and TIME separately when it's clear these are points in time and the two values are more important together than apart? Anyway given the current schema you need to stop converting to string. Try this:

```
DECLARE @b TABLE (  
   CustomerID INT,
   DateFrom DATE,
   DateTo DATE,
   TimeFrom TIME,
   TimeTo TIME 
);

INSERT @b VALUES (11137,'2012-08-14','2012-08-16','00:33:46','03:33:46'),
                 (11138,'2012-08-15','2012-08-17','08:00:00','00:31:03'),
                 (11139,'2012-08-16','2012-08-17','22:46:25','00:46:25');

declare @fDate date
set @fDate = '2012-08-14' 

declare @tDate date
set @tDate = '2012-08-16'

declare @fTime time
set @fTime ='12:33:46 AM'

declare @tTime time
set @tTime='12:31:03 AM'

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT 
    CustomerID, DateFrom, TimeFrom, DateTo, TimeTo,
    [Start] = DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND,'00:00',TimeFrom), 
              CONVERT(DATETIME, DateFrom)),
    [End]   = DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND,'00:00',TimeTo),   
              CONVERT(DATETIME, DateTo))
  FROM @b
)
SELECT * FROM x WHERE [Start] 
  BETWEEN     CONVERT(DATETIME, @fDate) + CONVERT(DATETIME, @fTime)
          AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @tDate) + CONVERT(DATETIME, @tTime);
```