# How to list data between two dates in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried display 1 monthly data but I want display e.g  between 01.06.2013 and 01.07.2013 ? How to change this query for display between two date ? Thanks in advance

```
   select b.ID ID, bt.type BULTEN_TYPE, b.ID TOPIC, b.Bul_Effect EFFECTT, b.Bul_Comment COMMENTS, 

     concat(date_format(b.Bul_date,'%d.%m.%Y'), ' ', b.Bul_hour, ':', b.Bul_min) as BEGIN,      
     concat(date_format(b.bitdate,'%d.%m.%Y'), ' ', b.bithour
     , ':', b.bitmin) as FINISH from bulten b, bulten_type bt, statu s WHERE b.Bul_Type = bt.ID and   
      b.Status = s.ID and Bul_date >= date(now() - interval 1 month) order by ID desc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `WHERE` clause will get you exactly what you used as an example:

```
... and Bul_date BETWEEN '1/6/2013' AND '1/7/2013' ...
```

Now, a more dynamic way of getting at what I *think* you want would be:

```
... and Bul_date BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()) ...
```

that would get you everything between now, and a day from now.

Now, the problem with the last example is that `GETDATE()` has a time on it so if you wanted to strip that (i.e. to start from midnight) you could do this:

```
... and Bul_date BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) AND
        DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 select b.ID ID, 
      bt.type BULTEN_TYPE,
      b.ID TOPIC,
      b.Bul_Effect EFFECTT,
      b.Bul_Comment COMMENTS, 
     concat(date_format(b.Bul_date,'%d.%m.%Y'), ' ', b.Bul_hour, ':', b.Bul_min) as BEGIN,
     concat(date_format(b.bitdate,'%d.%m.%Y'), ' ', b.bithour
     , ':', b.bitmin) as FINISH 
     from bulten b, bulten_type bt, statu s
      WHERE b.Bul_Type = bt.ID and   
      b.Status = s.ID and 
     Month(Bul_date)=Month(GetDate()) and Year(Bul_date)=Year(GetDate()) 
     order by ID desc;
```

Comment: Thank you bro.But where I enter my dates ?

Comment: @MehmetAkyel it will automatically give u the curent month report if you want to provide your own range than give it in place of `GetDate()`

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
Bul_date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have find something for you. I think this might helps you

[SQL check record in between two dates and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220529/sql-check-record-in-betweens-two-dates-and-time)

Check this question